# TableViewCell with multiple columns

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, uitableview

I have an application in which I want to have a tableView with custom tableViewCell that has five columns.

I want them to be like 20%, 30%, 15%, 20% and 15% of the whole cell's width, because I want my application to launch on iPhone and iPad.

What is the best way to do this?

Now I have created a tableViewCell prototype with 5 labels. I also added constraints to them but the width constraint is just a constant. Also when I added width constraints to labels, some collisions appeared there and I don't know how to fix them.

[Here is a screenshot.](http://oi57.tinypic.com/2n9yrll.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can create table view cell with collection view. By that, you can get different part in cell as well as you can change each column width programmatically based on your needs.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give some examples of it. I found one with objective-C, but I can't convert in to swift. http://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell/

Answer (score 0):

A table view has only one column and allows vertical scrolling only. [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)

If you want to use a few columns, you can use UICollectionViewController

Answer (score 0):

> I also added constraints to them but the width constraint is just a constant. Also when I added width constraints to labels, some collisions appeared there and I don't know how to fix them

To fix it change width constraints to be a multiplier of superview width.

[image]